# Proving connectedness of a topological group using identity component

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, metric-spaces, connectedness, topological-groups

Consider the following situation: Let $G$ be a topological group with identity element $e \in G$ and let $G_0$ denote the *identity component of $G$*, i.e. the connected component of $e$ (actually, the topology of $G$ is induced by a metric $d$, i.e. $(G, d)$ is a metric space).

From standard results on topological groups, it follows that $G_0$ is a closed, characteristic subgroup of $G$, i.e. $G_0$ is a closed subset of the topological space $G$ and $\phi(G_0) \subseteq G_0$ for every group automorphism $\phi$ of $G$ (in particular, $G_0$ is a normal subgroup). Moreover, the factor group $G/G_0$ consists of all connected components of the topological space $G$ and is a totally disconnected topological group.

Furthermore, in my current situation, the following special properties hold:

- If the sequence $(g_n)_n \subseteq G$ converges to the identity element $e$ in $G$, then, for every $f \in G$, the sequence $(f \circ g_n)_n \subseteq G$ converges to $f$ in $G$.
- The metric $d$ (see above) is invariant under right multiplication, i.e. $d(f \circ g, h \circ g) = d(f, h)$ for all $f, g, h \in G$.

> I'd like to show that the topological group $G$ is connected.

Therefore, I assume that $G$ is **not** connected and try to construct a contradiction. If $G$ is not connected, then $G_0$ is a *proper* normal subgroup of $G$, i.e. $G_0 \not = G$. Hence, there exists $f \in G \backslash G_0$ such that the connected component $C_f$ of $f$ and $G_0$ are disjont, i.e. $C_f \cap G_0 = \emptyset$ (note that $C_f = f \circ G_0 = G_0 \circ f$).

Can anybody give me a hint on how to proceed here, or does anybody see how to create the desired contradiction? Thanks in advance for any comment/hint etc.!

**EDIT:**
As A.Rod pointed out, the first property is satisfied in every topological group, hence this is nothing special here. Furthermore, let me explain why I'd like $G$ to be connected: There are two proper topological subgroups $U_1, U_2 \leq G$ (i.e. $U_1, U_2$ are closed subgroups of $G$) that are both connected - hence, it may be likely that $G$ itself is connected as well.

Comment: The first condition is automatically satisfied in a topological group, it's the continuity of the left multiplication.
I doubt this is enough to make your group connected. For instance, for $O(n)$.

Comment: Is it necessary that $G$ is connected, though? Maybe I am missing something, but taking $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$ with the discrete topology, and $d$ the discrete metric, won't this be a topological group with a right-invariant metric which is disconnected?

Comment: @A.Rod thanks for your hint - of course, this condition is satisfied in every topological group. @ mcwiggler interesting point - to be honest, I don't know whether connectedness is necessary in this situation ;-) But I would like my group $G$ to be connected, due to the fact that there are actually two proper topological subgroup $U_1, U_2 \leq G$ that are connected (maybe I should've stated this in my question as well...). This is the reason why I'm heading for connectedness!

Comment: Just to clarifiy my 1st comment, when I said "I doubt that this is enough to make your group connected". I meant both conditions 1 (which is automatically satisfied as I said) and 2. 
And the example of mcwiggler, or the one I gave, $O(n)$ provide examples of topological groups where the 2nd condition (and the 1st one also, of course) is satisfied but are not connected.

Comment: I don't see why the additionnal property that you have should change anything. Then again take $G=O(n)$, $U_1=\{1\}$  and $U_2=SO(n)$.

Comment: I have a question : why is $G_0$ characteristic ? What happens for discontinuous automorphisms ?

Comment: @Max see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_component#Properties

Comment: So it *is* only for continuous automorphisms

Comment: @Max yes seems as if...however, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup#Topological_groups, there it also says that $G_0$ is indeed a characteristic subgroup of $G$.